# Lambda expression and Optional how to return String value

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to get an Optional value, I have something like this:

```
Optional<String> value =

Optional.ofNullable(MyObject.getPeople())
    .ifPresent(people -> people                                                                    
        .stream()                                                                    
        .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test1"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(person -> person.getId()));
```

person.getId() should return a string, I tried this but it didn't work, getting incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.util.Optional

```
Optional<String> value =

Optional.ofNullable(MyObject.getPeople())
    .ifPresent(people -> people                                                                    
        .stream()                                                                    
        .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test1"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(person -> person.getId()))
        .orElse(null);
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`Optional.ifPresent` takes a `Consumer` - so you cannot return anything from it. Use `Optional.map`.

```
Optional.ofNullable(MyObject.getPeople())
    .map(people -> people                                                                    
        .stream()                                                                    
        .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test1"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(person -> person.getId()))
    .orElse(null);
```

A better one would be to use `flatmap` and not return a null at the end (It is not recommended to assign `null` to an Optional variable)

```
Optional.ofNullable(MyObject.getPeople())
    .flatmap(people -> people                                                                    
        .stream()                                                                    
        .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test1"))
        .findFirst()
        .map(person -> person.getId()));
```

*Note:* Your first statement is also a bit weird. If `MyObject.getPeople` returns a collection, then there is no need to wrap it with an Optional (unless the return value could be *null* - but again, it is recommended not to return *null* when the return type is a Collection).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming people is a `Collection`, the first use of Optional is not needed. You may do it like so,

```
Optional<String> value = MyObject.getPeople().stream()
    .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test1"))
    .findFirst().map(person -> person.getId());
```

If there exists a value it will return it, otherwise it will return an empty Optional.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need a nested lambda for that. Return `Collections.emptyList()` on `orElse` instead.

```
Optional<String> value = Optional.ofNullable(MyObject.getPeople())
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getName().equals("test"))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Person::getId);
```

Comment: :) Recently I came up with the same idea when I was needing to map from optional<stream<string>> to pure stream to proceed calls chain. :) It was not too easy...

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList("ABC","LMN","XYZ");`

Optional<String> optName1 = Optional.ofNullable(nameList)
            .orElse(Collections.empty list())
            .stream()
            .filter(name->"XYZ123".equals(name))
            .findAny();

if(optName1.isPresent()){
            System.out.println("---->"+optName1.get());
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).